# simulation nodes not distribute with the rule

Tags: d3.js, simulation

Below example try to put node from top to bottom but it overlapped each other now.

```js
    test()
    
    function test() {
            var nodes = [
                    {"Name":"A","Count":10},
                    {"Name":"B","Count":8},
          {"Name":"C","Count":6},
          {"Name":"D","Count":5},
          {"Name":"E","Count":4},
          {"Name":"F","Count":4},
          {"Name":"G","Count":2},
          {"Name":"H","Count":7},
            ]
            
            var width = 600
            var height = 600
            var margin = 100
            var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
            
            let extentCount = d3.extent(nodes, d => d.Count)            
            let maxRadius = 50 
            
            let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain(extentCount)
                .range([height - maxRadius, maxRadius])
            
            let rScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
                .domain(extentCount)
                .range([5, maxRadius])
            
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
                    .attr("height", height + margin + margin)
                    .attr("class", "bubble")
                    .style('border','2px solid red')
                    .style('background','#ececec')
            
            var g = svg.append("g")
                .attr('transform', `translate(${margin},${margin})`)

            var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
                    //.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(0).strength(1))
                    .force("forceX", d3.forceX().strength(.051).x(width/2))
                    .force("forceY", d3.forceY().strength(.051).y(d => yScale(d.Count)))
                    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => rScale(d.Count)))

            simulation.stop()
            
            var node = g.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;
                    });

            node.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", d => rScale(d.Count))
                    .style("fill", function(d,i) {
                            return color(i);
                    });

            node.append("text")
                    .attr("dy", ".2em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function(d) {
                            return d.Name.substring(0, rScale(d.Count) / 3);
                    })
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", function(d){
                            return rScale(d.Count)/5;
                    })
                    .attr("fill", "white");

            node.append("text")
                    .attr("dy", "1.3em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function(d) {
                            return d.Count;
                    })
                    .attr("font-family",  "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT")
                    .attr("font-size", function(d){
                            return d.r/5;
                    })
                    .attr("fill", "white");

            function ticked() {
          node
              .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
                            .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
            }
            
            simulation.on("tick",ticked)
            simulation.nodes(nodes)
            //simulation.force("link").links(links)
            simulation.alpha(1).restart()
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG `<g>` elements have no `cy` or `cx` attributes. Inside the `tick` function, it should be:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;
});
```

Here's your code with that change:

```js
test()

function test() {
  var nodes = [{
      "Name": "A",
      "Count": 10
    },
    {
      "Name": "B",
      "Count": 8
    },
    {
      "Name": "C",
      "Count": 6
    },
    {
      "Name": "D",
      "Count": 5
    },
    {
      "Name": "E",
      "Count": 4
    },
    {
      "Name": "F",
      "Count": 4
    },
    {
      "Name": "G",
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "Name": "H",
      "Count": 7
    },
  ]

  var width = 600
  var height = 600
  var margin = 100
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

  let extentCount = d3.extent(nodes, d => d.Count)
  let maxRadius = 50

  let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(extentCount)
    .range([height - maxRadius, maxRadius])

  let rScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain(extentCount)
    .range([5, maxRadius])

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
    .attr("height", height + margin + margin)
    .attr("class", "bubble")
    .style('border', '2px solid red')
    .style('background', '#ececec')

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin},${margin})`)

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    //.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(0).strength(1))
    .force("forceX", d3.forceX().strength(.051).x(width / 2))
    .force("forceY", d3.forceY().strength(.051).y(d => yScale(d.Count)))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => rScale(d.Count)))

  simulation.stop()

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");


  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", d => rScale(d.Count))
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    });

  node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".2em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.Name.substring(0, rScale(d.Count) / 3);
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", function(d) {
      return rScale(d.Count) / 5;
    })
    .attr("fill", "white");

  node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", "1.3em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.Count;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT")
    .attr("font-size", function(d) {
      return d.r / 5;
    })
    .attr("fill", "white");

  function ticked() {
    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;
    });
  }

  simulation.on("tick", ticked)
  simulation.nodes(nodes)
  //simulation.force("link").links(links)
  simulation.alpha(1).restart()
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```